# what is the best wrapper implementation of grpc c++?

Tags: c++, templates, grpc

with a example service as below, every rpc shares some same codes of validating the request->var1().

What we want to do is to abstract the public wrapper method to do the validation.

```
class MyGrpcImpl final : public ::MyGrpcService::Service {
 public:
  explicit MyGrpcImpl(std::string config_path);

  ::grpc::Status ExampleRPC(::grpc::ServerContext *context,
                            const ::ExampleRPCReq *request,
                            ::ExampleRPCReply *response) override;
  ::grpc::Status ExampleRPC2(::grpc::ServerContext *context,
                             const ::ExampleRPC2Req *request,
                             ::ExampleRPC2Reply *response) override;

} ::grpc::Status MyGrpcImpl::ExampleRPC(::grpc::ServerContext *context,
                                        const ::ExampleRPCReq *request,
                                        ::ExampleRPCReply *response) {
  if (validate_argument(request->var1())) {
    return grpc::Status(grpc::StatusCode::INVALID_ARGUMENT, "INVALID_ARGUMENT");
  }

  // process request ,may return grpc error

  return grpc::Status::OK;
}

::grpc::Status MyGrpcImpl::ExampleRPC2(::grpc::ServerContext *context,
                                       const ::ExampleRPC2Req *request,
                                       ::ExampleRPC2Reply *response) {
  if (validate_argument(request->var1())) {
    return grpc::Status(grpc::StatusCode::INVALID_ARGUMENT, "INVALID_ARGUMENT");
  }

  // process request ,may return grpc error

  return grpc::Status::OK;
};
```

using my superficial knowledge of template, I get a this below.

```
class MyGrpcImpl final : public ::MyGrpcService::Service {
 public:
  explicit MyGrpcImpl(std::string config_path);

  ::grpc::Status ExampleRPC(::grpc::ServerContext *context,
                            const ::ExampleRPCReq *request,
                            ::ExampleRPCReply *response) override;
  ::grpc::Status ExampleRPC2(::grpc::ServerContext *context,
                             const ::ExampleRPC2Req *request,
                             ::ExampleRPC2Reply *response) override;
  template <typename From, typename To, typename FuncType>
  grpc::Status ProcessRequest(::grpc::ServerContext *context, From request,
                              To response, FuncType &func);
};
template <typename From, typename To, typename FuncType>
grpc::Status ProxySeverImpl::ProcessRequest(::grpc::ServerContext *context,
                                            From request, To response,
                                            FuncType &func) {
  if (validate_argument(request->var1())) {
    return grpc::Status(grpc::StatusCode::INVALID_ARGUMENT, "INVALID_ARGUMENT");
  }
  auto handler = get_handler();
  func(request, response, handler);
};

::grpc::Status MyGrpcImpl::ExampleRPC(::grpc::ServerContext *context,
                                      const ::ExampleRPCReq *request,
                                      ::ExampleRPCReply *response) {
  auto lambda = [](const ExampleRPCReq *request, ExampleRPCReply *response,
                   handller inner_handler) -> grpc::Status {
    // process request ,may return grpc error
  };
  return ProcessRequest<decltype(request), decltype(response),
                        decltype(lambda)>(context, request, response, lambda);
}

::grpc::Status MyGrpcImpl::ExampleRPC2(::grpc::ServerContext *context,
                                       const ::ExampleRPC2Req *request,
                                       ::ExampleRPC2Reply *response) {
  auto lambda = [](const ExampleRPC2Req *request, ExampleRPC2Reply *response,
                   handller inner_handler) -> grpc::Status {
    // process request ,may return grpc error
  };
  return ProcessRequest<decltype(request), decltype(response),
                        decltype(lambda)>(context, request, response, lambda);
};
```

but the lambda declaration forces me to say it again about the request type and the response type, is there a better solution to avoid the repeated declaration?

Comment: Doesn't `ProcessRequest(context, request, response, lambda)` without the template arguments work?

Comment: It works, but I want to save the lines of `auto lambda = [](const ExampleRPC2Req *request, ExampleRPC2Reply *response,
                   handller inner_handler) -> grpc::Status {`

Comment: Couldn't you use `auto`? `auto lambda = [](auto request, auto response, auto inner_handler) .{ .. };`

Comment: using auto will make request have no type intelligence hint.

Comment: Alternatively, you can capture the arguments in the lambda in which case, you need to send only `request` to `ProcessRequest`. `auto lambda = [&]() {...};  return ProcessRequest(request, lambda)`.